# Using ModelBuilder to join table to shapefile in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have more than 40 shapefiles and tables. I want to join the table of attribute of these shapefiles with related  tables permanently. For small number of shapefiles and tables, I normally join shapefiles table of attribute with related table and then export the shapefile and save it as a new name.But how can i do it in ModelBuilder for large number of shapefiles?

Comment: Maybe link below has some information that may help you


http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115066/using-modelbuilder-to-iterate-join-export-feature-classes

Comment: The solution is going to depend on whether you can build the relationship programatically. Can you tell us more about the relationship? Is it 1 table for each shapefile? Do the shapefiles and tables have matching names? Some other relationship?

Comment: You can replace the join table > export result to new file workflow with the [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool. However it's unclear from your question if this is really what you're trying to do, because you mention *related* tables, which is a whole different story and typically implies a one-to-many relationship - which you can't do/make permanent without duplicating features. More information is needed about your tables and their relationships to determine what you're really trying to do and how to go about it.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment. I was looking for Join field tools. I had  a raster and a counties border shape file and wanted to extract some data with zonal statistics as table based on counties and then add these data (in this case average of Ndvi Values in each county) to the shape file ToA .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) tool within ModelBuilder to add fields from a table to a feature class/shapefile based on a join, without the need to export a new file to make the join permanent.